# Pandas - Merge two dataframes add non-desired rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, dataframe, merge

Here's my problem. In the contexte of a ML project on 2015 MLB matchups I have two dataframes:

One dataframe with the matchup details of the 2015 season with AND the result of my predictive model (the following image).

[image]

And another dataframe with also de the matchup details of the 2015 season AND the odd for each team on a given matchup.

[image]

My goal is to merge both dataframe using matchup detail columns as keys ("Visitor_Team","V_Team_PTS","Home_Team",H_Team_PTS) to get the odds and the results of my model correspond for each matchup (each observation) for further analysis.

So I tried the following code:

```
df = pd.merge(model_df, odds_df, on = ['Visitor_Team','V_Team_PTS', 'Home_Team','H_Team_PTS'], how = "inner")
```

It does well for the major part of the job but it gives me additionnal rows because the "merge()" function does not take into account the order while looking for match in both dataframes. 
So let's imagine a matchup like:

```
V_Team  V_PTS H_Team  H_PTS   Conf   V_Odds   H_Odds   Date
NYY     3     ARI     4       0.6532 1.45     1.98     06/04/2015
```

When I implement the function, it also take matchup where these 2 teams meet and by coincidence with the same score (whatever the order 3-4,4-3) if it exists and create a new row on the same date but with different odds (it takes odds for the other game).

So, I have additionnal rows like these (only odd values differ):

```
V_Team  V_PTS H_Team  H_PTS   Confidence   V_Odds   H_Odds   Date
NYY     3     ARI     4       0.6532       1.45     1.98     06/04/2015
NYY     3     ARI     4       0.6532       1.75     2.04     06/04/2015
NYY     3     ARI     4       0.6532       2.32     1.45     06/04/2015
```

Here's an example:

[image]

Which actually makes no sense. Despite of intense research in pandas docs I do not figure out how to avoid this kind of "semi-duplication". Does anyone have an idea? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you inner join and receive more rows in the resulting table, it's typically because one or more of the tables has duplicate rows on the join key (ie. the ON part). Do either of your tables have duplicates on this key?

Comment: @AlexPetralia Yes both may have duplicates based on these key columns

Comment: Should there be duplicates, or should the duplicates be dropped? If not dropped, can you post an example of the duplicate rows in a DataFrame you are leaving in?